# PHP execution time measurement precision

Tags: php

So I measure execution time like this:

```
$time = -microtime(true);
...
$time += microtime(true);
```

PHP version is 5.3.26RC1 x86 running on Win Server 2008 x64 machine.
"Precision" ini parameter equals 16.
However, each time the execution time is below 0.001, it just returns zero (obviously, the script can't be executed instantly!).
What's even more strange, my test machine (standard php.ini-development) returns nonzero values even if there is no code between these two statements... What could be wrong?

Upd: Simple test:

```
<?php
ini_set('precision',16);
echo php_uname() . PHP_EOL;
echo phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
echo ini_get('precision').PHP_EOL;

$time = -microtime(true);
$time += microtime(true);
echo number_format($time, 10) .PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Test machine output:

```
Windows NT XXX 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
5.4.12
16
0.0000028610
```

Production machine output:

```
Windows NT XXX 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586
5.3.26RC1
16
0.0000000000
```

Comment: You're asking too much (especially on Windows)... You really shouldn't expect accuracy below 0.001 seconds, especially in a scripting language.

Comment: Can you show the code that's displaying the time? When I try `microtime(true)` with code just as you have it shows 13 decimals (default PHP settings, on Windows). Are you sure you aren't formatting your output?

Comment: How you printng value?

Comment: Just put your `microtime` calls into a long loop and you will see what is going on.

Comment: I've updated the question with some tests

Comment: Upd.: performed some more tests. Both PHP 5.2 and 5.4 return nonzero values. Only 5.3 (both RC and non-RC) has this problem. Well, maybe this behavior is more correct, considering Prof. Falken' s answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your platform, Windows, can not discriminate between such small times, with the standard time calls.

A comment from the PHP source code:

"on windows, time_sleep_until has millisecond accuracy while **microtime()** is accurate to 10th of a second."

(In `ext/standard/tests/misc/time_sleep_until_basic.phpt`.)